# What is more appropriate for the word "time"?

Tags: time

I want to write a scientific writing. I do not know what is more appropriate for "slack time".
For example:
which of these is correct?
Slack time is small.
Slack time is short.
or
Slack time is large.
Slack time is big.
and ...
Thank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

English has two ways of speaking about *time*.

- as a linear duration, a **length**: *long*, *longer*, *short*, *shorter, *brief*, *briefer*. These *length* terms are used only when you are talking about the duration of individual timespans.

  > It’s a long time until my birthday.
  >   I lived in Boston for only a brief time.
  >   John’s time in the 200-meter was shorter today than yesterday.
  >   Slack time on the 17th of May was unusually long.
- as an **amount**: *much*, *a lot*, *little*, *a little*, *less*. These usually express aggregate times rather than individual timespans:

  > I spent a lot of time in the library.
  >   We have a little time off now.

  However, an *amount* term may qualify a specific timespan when you are speaking of the sufficiency of time—whether there is enough time to accomplish something:

  > We don’t have much time to finish this project.

Note the *amount* terms cannot be employed as predicate adjectives; in constructions of the form *Time BE X*, X must be expressed with *length* terms.

> <sup>∗</sup> Slack time was much.
>   <sup>ok</sup> Slack time was long.

Consequently, if you are speaking of aggregate amounts you will have to recast your sentence into another form:

> There was much slack time.

---

<sup>∗</sup>  marks an utterance as ungrammatical.

Comment: Thank. But i saw in some of prestigious journals that they have used some sentences like " the slack time is very small".

Comment: @Finder Ah. A little googling suggests that *slack time* here is a 'term of art' in systems analysis/programming, not ordinary English. When you're working with a professional jargon, the rules of ordinary English no longer apply. Questions like this  should not be asked here, but on an SE site in your particular specialty, where experts in the field can answer it. I suggest you browse the SE sites and use the 'flag' button under your question to ask the moderators to migrate your question to whichever site you think most appropriate.